# How can i make long query in django

Tags: python, django

I have this query filter. But I don't know how to make it work

```
st = Student.objects.filter(
    if request.GET['student_number']:
        Q(student_number__icontains=request.GET['student_number'])&
    if request.GET['student_region']:
        Q(student_region__icontains=request.GET['student_region']) &
    if request.GET['student_status']:
        Q(student_status__icontains=request.GET['student_status']) &
    if request.GET['student_process']:
        Q(student_process__name__icontains=request.GET['student_process']) &
```

Is there any better way of doing that?

Comment: what about multiple chained filter() i.e. Student.objects.filter().filter() etc looks better to me.

Comment: A side note: don't use raw data from the GET request like in your example, always clean it!

Comment: can you give me example for that for my case. or is there any automatic way of making that filter list  like put in kwargs and then loop through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the query dynamically like so:

```
query_list = []
for field_name in ['student_process', 'student_status', 'student_number', 'student_region', ]:
    value = request.GET.get(field_name, None)
    if value:
        query_list.append(Q(**{field_name+'s_icontains': value}))
queryset = Student.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, query_list))
```

[Here's a good blog post on the topic](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2009/09/12/django-python-dynamically-create-queries-from-a-string-and-the-or-operator/)